# NVME on PCIe on Gigabyte x570UD 1.0

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, nvme

I bought **two** NVME of 4TB each that I plugged on a PCIexpress extension card on my motherboard.

Let me name the two newly bought NVMEs:

- NVME1
- NVME2

*(see below for more details)*

## The problem

I can NEVER see BOTH NVME1 and NVME2 working at the same time.

I can ONLY see NVME1 when it's plugged on port1 of the PCIe extension card

or I can ONLY see NVME2 when it's plugged on port1 of the PCIe extension card

---

Below I try to clarify the issue, but it might just be confusing :')

In other other words, any NVME plugged anywhere else than on port1 of the extension card will not be seen/recognized by the computer.

For information there are 4 ports on the PCIe extension card -> I tried ALL permutations of ports and NVME -> None of them work, except when any NVME is plugged on Port1 -> then it'll be seen by the computer.

It does not matter whether a NVME is plugged on port 2,3 or 4 -> as long as there's something on port1, only stuff on port1 will be seen.

---

## What I tried to do

- I tried all possible permutations  of NVME1 and NVME2 on the extension card -> only the nvme plugged on port1 is visible/recognized by the computer
- I removed ALL other PCIexpress extension cards. There were two of them: a WiFi card and a USB3 extension card -> removing them did not improve the detection of the additional NVME
- In the BIOS I tried the PCIe express configuration from Auto to 4x4, etc. -> the result is always the same, only one NVME is seen
- All the above attempts have been checked on both Windows 10 Pro and Linux (Linux Mint 5.15.0-82-generic)

## Hardware Setup

### Plugged on the motherboard

On the motherboard on the dedicated port there is a 1TB NVME, let's call it NVME0

There is a GeForce RTX3080Ti in the "main" PCIexpress slot

And NO other PCIexpress extension card aside from the one with the NVMEs installed on it.

### Motherboard

My computer is equipped with this motherboard: Gibabyte x570 UD V1.0: https://www.gigabyte.com/fr/Motherboard/X570-UD-rev-10#kf

The BIOS on the motherboard is up to date with the lastest update F37 from 26/12/2022 (or 12/26/2022 if you're writing your dates wrong :D)

### The NVMEs

I bought TWO 4TB NVME here:
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B0B25M8FXX?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

### The PCIexpress extension card

The card I plug the NVMEs on was bought here: https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B0BV7GBXMP?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

## Questions/remarks

### Remarks n.1

I am a little afraid that my motherboard X570UD rev 1.0 cannot be able to accept that much PCIe peripherals/NVME?

Could that be a chipset issue?

### Question 1

Have you noticed anything obvious that I might have missed?

### Question 2

Do you think the motherboard is incompatible with what I am trying to do?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It's possible this adapter card can only work with PCIe bifurcation.

Comment: @DanielB I tried all settings possible for PCIe bifurcation -> with identical results. Only the NVME drive installed on port1 of the extension card is visible

Comment: The adapter really needs x16 and your only true x16 slot is used by the graphics. The others are x16 slots running at x8 and x4 respectively. Please check your motherboard's specifications.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yep, I think you're right :') that might be the issue indeed

Comment: Modern computer. Modern disks. And a card of a type I haven't used since the late 90s....

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have run into the data-lanes limitation of your PCIe setup.

Your PCIe 4.0 M.2 expansion card may be able to connect two M.2 drives.
But if that card runs PCIe 4.0 at x4 (which is as fast as your slot will
allow), and if you have two PCIe 4.0 M.2 drives, then, as
M.2 needs x4 speeds, only one drive will be usable on that expansion card
at full speed.

You could perhaps get by with two 4.0 expansion cards,
one for each 4.0 drive. You could then possibly have two drives with
such a setup but they might not reach full speed, especially if both are
used at the same time.

It's impossible to know in advance whether two 4.0 expansion cards
will work, because these details of the motherboard are not published.

Comment: Ok weirdly my comment did not go through. So anyway, what I did is this: I ordered a new smaller expansion card, supposed to fit in PCIeX4 slot. I'll come back here and keep this topic up to date based on what happens. (I'll probably edit my original post)

Comment: I saw your previous comment and it has truly disappeared. Normally this means that a moderator thought it superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in the end is:

I bought an additional small PCIe expansion card to install the remaining NVME.

So for reference (not an affiliated link) on the motherboard Gigabyte X570 UD rev 1.0, I had to plug:

- This:
  https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B0BV7GBXMP?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details
- And this:
  https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B07FN3YZ8P?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

In order to be able to have two NVME plugged via PCIe.